# Filter unique value per key in angularjs and get checked

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular object, i have to show its records with filter and sorting. Also i have to show the records of unique values per keys within the object with checkbox.
I shows record with filter and sorting also i showed the unique values per key with checkbox.
Now i have to get the values of these checkbox per key.

Here is my code with plunker url below.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
<label ng-repeat="option in structure.tabs">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.selected">{{option.index}}
</label>
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in structure.tabs" ng-show="header.selected" ng-click="sortData(header.filter)">{{header.index}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in structure.info | orderBy:sortColumn:reverseSort">
        <td ng-show="structure.tabs[0].selected">{{data.name}}</td>
        <td ng-show="structure.tabs[1].selected">{{data.age}}</td>
        <td ng-show="structure.tabs[2].selected">{{data.city}}</td>
        <td ng-show="structure.tabs[3].selected">{{data.designation}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1>Unique Values Table (per key)</h1>
<table border="1" width="100%" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header1 in structure.tabs" ng-show="header1.selected">{{header1.index}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="(hk, hv) in structure.tabs" ng-show="hv.selected">
            <table border='1'>
                <tr ng-repeat="(dk, dv) in structure.info | unique:hv.filter">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox">{{dv[hv.filter]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <button ng-click="getChecked(hv.filter)">Get Checked</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("myController", function ($scope,$log) {
$scope.sortColumn="name";
$scope.reverseSort=false;

$scope.sortData=function(column) {
    $scope.reverseSort=($scope.sortColumn==column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
    $scope.sortColumn=column;
}

$scope.structure={
    "tabs": [
        {
            "index": "Name",
            "filter": "name",
            "selected": true
        },
        {
            "index": "Age",
            "filter": "age",
            "selected": true
        },
        {
            "index": "City",
            "filter": "city",
            "selected": true
        },
        {
            "index": "Designation",
            "filter": "designation",
            "selected": true
        }
    ],
    "info": [
        {
            "name": "Abar",
            "age": "27",
            "city": "Ghaziabad",
            "designation": "Php Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Abar",
            "age": "27",
            "city": "Okhla",
            "designation": "Html Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nishant",
            "age": "25",
            "city": "Delhi",
            "designation": "Angular Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Amit",
            "age": "30",
            "city": "Noida",
            "designation": "Android Developer"
        }
    ]
};

$scope.getChecked = function(tab) {
    alert("Need to get all checked value of key: "+tab);
}
});
app.filter('unique', function() {
return function (arr, field) {
    var o = {}, i, l = arr.length, r = [];
    for(i=0; i<l;i+=1) {
        o[arr[i][field]] = arr[i];
    }
    for(i in o) {
        r.push(o[i]);
    }
    return r;
};
});
```

See in plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/wblXhejmSWApBeCAusaI/

Comment: Where do you want the value of the checkbox to be stored?

Comment: simply alert for now

Comment: What is the value that you want it to alert?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />'); </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
<h1>Filter Table</h1>
<label ng-repeat="option in structure.tabs">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.selected">{{option.index}}
</label>
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in structure.tabs" ng-show="header.selected" ng-click="sortData(header.filter)">{{header.index}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in structure.info | orderBy:sortColumn:reverseSort">
        <td ng-show="structure.tabs[0].selected">{{data.name}}</td>
        <td ng-show="structure.tabs[1].selected">{{data.age}}</td>
        <td ng-show="structure.tabs[2].selected">{{data.city}}</td>
        <td ng-show="structure.tabs[3].selected">{{data.designation}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1>Unique Values Table (per key)</h1>
<table border="1" width="100%" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header1 in structure.tabs" ng-show="header1.selected">{{header1.index}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="(hk, hv) in structure.tabs" ng-show="hv.selected">
            <table border='1'>
                <tr ng-repeat="(dk, dv) in structure.info | unique:hv.filter">
                    <td>
                        <input ng-model="item" type="checkbox" ng-change="getCheckedValues(item,dv,hv.filter)">{{dv[hv.filter]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <button  ng-click="getChecked(hv.filter)">Get Checked</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("myController", function ($scope,$log) {

```
$scope.sortColumn="name";
$scope.reverseSort=false;

$scope.sortData=function(column) {
    $scope.reverseSort=($scope.sortColumn==column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
    $scope.sortColumn=column;
}
var array = []
array["name"] = [];
array["age"] = [];
array["designation"] = [];
array["city"] = [];
$scope.getCheckedValues = function(e,val,key){
    console.log(val)
    if(e){
        array[key].push(e)
    }else{
        array[key].shift()
    }
}

$scope.structure={
    "tabs": [
        {
            "index": "Name",
            "filter": "name",
            "selected": true
        },
        {
            "index": "Age",
            "filter": "age",
            "selected": true
        },
        {
            "index": "City",
            "filter": "city",
            "selected": true
        },
        {
            "index": "Designation",
            "filter": "designation",
            "selected": true
        }
    ],
    "info": [
        {
            "name": "Abar",
            "age": "27",
            "city": "Ghaziabad",
            "designation": "Php Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Abar",
            "age": "27",
            "city": "Okhla",
            "designation": "Html Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nishant",
            "age": "25",
            "city": "Delhi",
            "designation": "Angular Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Amit",
            "age": "30",
            "city": "Noida",
            "designation": "Android Developer"
        }
    ]
};

$scope.getChecked = function(tab) {
    alert("Need to get all checked value of key: "+tab);
    console.log(array[tab])
  }
 });

 app.filter('unique', function() {
   return function (arr, field) {
    var o = {}, i, l = arr.length, r = [];
    for(i=0; i<l;i+=1) {
        o[arr[i][field]] = arr[i];
    }
    for(i in o) {
        r.push(o[i]);
    }
    return r;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Apologies for my previous answer I completely botched the question.

Anyhow I spent almost an hour trying to solve this and managed to do it using $scope.$$watchers[0].last and underscorejs.

```
//this is how getChecked looks like now
$scope.getChecked = function(tab) {
    var selectedKey = tab.$$watchers[0].last;
    _.each($scope.structure.info,function(row){
        _(row).pairs().filter(function(item){
        _.each(item,function(key){
            if(key===selectedKey)
                {
                    console.log(row);
                    return;
                }
        })

    })
    })
```

Above method is responsible for identifying the key and spitting in console, each time you select a key in below table. So check console.

The solution is on below plunkr.

https://embed.plnkr.co/kbiCwhW0RrdHtO3hVEEk/

Comment: This is little more than "here's a library which has some related functions, now go to this link and find the answer yourself". Change it to be "here's a library with some related functions. Here are some examples of how to use those related functions."

Comment: ...What I was trying to get at was that linking to outside content isn't very helpful. Include the answer to the question in your answer. Feel free to have links to support the answer, but it should answer the question if you stripped out the links.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes can you please remove the negative vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote this, so... not without doing something illegal, no.